# problem: caret in editbox keeps moving to left

Tags: c++, windows

I have the same problem as said in below article.
When user input '1', '2', instead of '12', '21' was displayed in edit box...

My question is:
How can I figure out why this happen?
I want caret stop being moved to the left.

> the caret position is set to the beginning of
> the EditBox once my function changes the length of the string in it,
> preventing continuous typing.

[Caret position in EditBox after change in text length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70665163/caret-position-in-editbox-after-change-in-text-length)